# special-delivery gem rails configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I can't get my `EmailCallback::MailgunEmail < SpecialDelivery::Callback` class to be included in execution. My problem is I'm not clear on where and how to create and call the new class mentioned in the readme. Currently when I fire of a POST request to the `mount SpecialDelivery::Engine => "/email_events"` endpoint with all correct params, it is processed by `SpecialDelivery::EventsController#create`. An object is instantiated but not saved.

For reference; the gem readme section: https://github.com/vigetlabs/special-delivery#your-custom-callback-class-file

I ran the undocumented rake task (special_delivery:install:migrations) and migrated to new migration file.

I currently have:

```
# /lib/email_callback/mailgun_email.rb

module EmailCallback
  class MailgunEmail < SpecialDelivery::Callback
    def opened
      require 'pry'; binding.pry
    end

    def create
      require 'pry'; binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I'm trying to hit the pry debugger to confirm the request is hitting the appropriate method and to see what I have to work with.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new class should be referenced in your invocation of the `#special_delivery` method that wraps your email sending.

```
def send_your_email(user)
  special_delivery(
    callback_class:  EmailCallback::MailgunEmail, # Here!
    callback_record: user
  ) do
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Hello from Kit!')
  end
end
```

Let me know if that works for you. If not we can dive in a bit deeper and get this sorted out for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally in the ReadMe. I don't know why I didn't make the connection.

Comment: I am having a new problem. Can you confirm where I'm supposed to put the new class.

At the moment I am getting the following error. `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Engine, expected /Users/Kit/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/special-delivery-0.1.3/lib/special_delivery/engine.rb to define it):`